# htaccess to redirect to sub directory

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have setup apache on ubuntu with the following doc root "/var/www/html". I have a html/css website running on server as well as a laravel application.

The laravel application is deployed with the following directory structure.

```
/var/www/html/myapp
```

For Laravel applications, the index file is located under public i.e.

```
/var/www/html/myapp/public
```

If I use the following url "www.example/myapp/public" all is good, but
I want the user to just type the url like "www.example/myapp" to access the application.

For that purpose, I have created a .htaccess file and placed it under myapp folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* public/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

htaccess redirects the "www.example.com/myapp" requests to the public folder, but the index.php runs into issues.

```
[2018-08-23 18:09:38] production.ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) at /var/www/html/myapp/app/Http/Controllers/MainController.php:677)
```

Also, the public folder has htaccess (default httaccess included with laravel)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: This is an issue with your controller, not Apache. Please post the relevant section of `MainController.php` along with your PHP version.

Comment: The rewrite rule is likely a separate issue, and if you want to write requests into `public` and keep the rest of the URL, you should probably use `RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]`

Comment: If I may, for that purpose and as food for thought, I would have used the Alias directive instead of rewriting : Alias "/myapp" "/myapp/public" . Also, you shouldn't use a .htaccess file unless forced to (like when you don't have access to httpd.conf) but use the httpd.conf main configuration file for the RewriteRule.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried updating the htaccess as per your comment, but it seems to be the same error. The line 677 reads like this for MainController.php "catch(ErrorException | Exception  $e){" which I believe is valid php code. And also, if I access the application like http://www.example.com/myapp/public" then all is good.

Comment: Andre, I have added a Alias to the http conf file as well. The problem with that is, it re-directs to the public folder file and the index.php file loads correctly, but clicking any links on the index.php causes an internal server error on apache with the errors of too many redirects :(